# Reload activity Android

Tags: activity, android

Такая проблема, в приложении в случайном порядке выводятся изображения. Приложение в ориентации landscape. Каждый раз при блокировании устройства, выводятся уже другие изображения. Какие есть пути решения этой проблемы? Я так понял reload происходит из за смены ориентации экрана. Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

он может происходить из за чего угодно: ориентация, язык поменяли на телефоне, клавиатура появилась/исчезла и т.д.

решение: использовать метод Activity **onSaveIsntanceState(final Bundle state)**

[пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)